# Как переопределить id с помощью jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть блок `<div id = 'ee'></div>`
Нужно что бы при клике ему ставилось `id = 'rr'`
Как такое можно реализовать?

Comment: а зачем менять `id`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Для этого следует использовать функцию [attr](https://api.jquery.com/attr/).

```
<div id="ee">content here</div>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.3.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(function() { 
        $('#ee').on('click', function(e) { 
            $(this).attr('id', 'rr');
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Почти одновременно =)

Answer (score 2):

эх, похоже долго делал наглядность, опередили :) но всё равно выложу, чтобы не пропадало зря

```js
$('#ee').click(function() {
  $('#ee').attr('id', 'rr');
});
```

```css
div {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
#ee {
  background-color: #f00;
}
#rr {
  background-color: #0f0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="ee"></div>
```

Comment: Спасибо большое)Ничего зря не пропадает

Comment: @НикитаЩипилов, ага, но в любом случае считаю, что Andrei Katalkin предоставил самый быстрый и правильный ответ :)

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте вот такой вариант

```
$("#ee").click(function () {

    $("#ee").attr("id", "rr");


});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/73zA2/22/